# insert combined value into the database

Tags: php, mysql

I fetch total_amount value and insert into another table but i want to insert total_amount in one field and seperated by ",". How to do that?

[image]

I know Mysqli is latest version . but here mysql is working properly.

```
<?php
include('database/db.php');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$sql1="Insert into test(`total_amount`) values ('{$_POST['i']}')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Total Amount</td>
</tr>
<?php
$sql="Select * from tes1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($dtset=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo $dtset['total_amount']; 
?>"><?php echo $dtset['total_amount']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you should use PDO mysqli is old approach and mysql is deprecated.  and use Prepared Statement your code is widely open for SQL injection and XSS attack.

Comment: Could you be more clear? What do you mean by:  I want to insert total_amount in one field and seperated by "," ? Do you want multiple values like 4429.6,1155.2 in one column in your table or your form?

Comment: yes i want to insert multiple value together in one field.

Comment: @Jonshon: do not insert multiple comma-separated values in one field. It is a bad practice. There is perhaps another solution, but that would require you to explain us what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql="Select * from tes1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// Empty array
$amounts = [];
while($dtset=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // Push the amounts to the array.
    $amounts[] = $dtset['total_amount'];
}
// Implode will create a string from your array and seperates it with
// the chosen character
$combined = implode(",",$amounts);
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo 
        $combined; ?>">
    <?php echo $combined; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The while loop is now not part of the table row, but instead creates the array with all values first and then you can add the string created by implode to your hidden form field.